# Replace subset of data table with other data table

Tags: r, data.table

I feel a bit silly for this question, but I only want to something which I know how to do with a data.frame, but I have not yet found a nice way to do it in R. All other similar questions seem way more complicated for what I have in mind. I simply want to replace a subset of a data.table with another data.table only based on an row index and choosing some columns.

MWE follows

```
x.df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),
               b=c(2,NA,NA), 
               c=c(3,NA,NA))
x.dt <- data.table(x.df)
x.df.replace<- data.frame(b=c(10,11), c=c(22,21))
x.dt.replace<- data.table(x.df.replace)
```

This works like a charm in data Frame

```
x.df[is.na(x.df$b),2:3]<-x.df.replace
```

On the other hand I would like to call the columns by name and I only know how to replace each column individually, but not jointly

```
x.dt[is.na(b),]
x.dt[is.na(b),c:=x.dt.replace[,c]]
x.dt[is.na(b),b:=x.dt.replace[,b]]
x.dt[is.na(b), list(b,c)]<-x.dt.replace
x.dt[is.na(b), list(b,c):=x.dt.replace]
```

Comment: What is `x` object in `x[is.na(b),c:=x1[,c]]` ?

Comment: So what's wrong with `x.dt[is.na(b), 2:3 := x.dt.replace]`? (Which is an exact verbatism of the base R code)

Comment: Nothing, although I would have liked to used verbatim column names, thats why I tried the `list(b,c)`

Comment: You said "*This works like a charm in data Frame*" and now you say it's not what you want. Either-way, you can do `x.dt[is.na(b), c("b", "c") := x.dt.replace]` (which is also pritty much the same as you would with a normal data.frame - except the `:=` vs `<-` part).

Comment: Thanks you can post this as an answer and I will accept it. I thought that you were not supposed to use `c("b","c")` or character vectors to subset columns within data.table. Did that change? Thats why I tried `list(b,c)`. I am just confused why `x.dt[is.na(b), c("b","c"):= x.dt.replace] ]` works and `x.dt[is.na(b), list(b,c):= x.dt.replace] ]` does not as the output without `:=x.dt.replace` is the same

Comment: Where did you see such notations as `dt[, list() := ...]` in `data.table` before? Can't recall anything like that (unless my memory betrays me).

Comment: Honestly, I cannot remember but I have been doing this for some time now. It works? Should it not?

Comment: Can you show an example where it works? Btw, I don't see your messages if you don't ping me using @.

Comment: You can just use the MWE here:  `x.dt[is.na(b), list(b,c) ]` and `x.dt[is.na(b), c("b","c") ]` yield the same output and `all.equal` returns `TRUE` @DavidArenburg
Also here they discuss it partly http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf  
 `If 2 or more columns are required, use list() or .() instead:`
Probably i have been using it incorectly ever since

Comment: But there is no `:=` in your examples. Using `.()` without the `:=` assignment operator is the idiomatic data.table way for aggregation (equivalent to `dplyr::summarise`), but I never seen `.()` being used together with `:=` (equivalent to `dplyr::mutate`).

Comment: @MaxM just posted an answer that helped me to solve a similar problem. I may be nice to edit the name of the questio to include the fact that you want to replace multiple columns at once, so people can find it easily in their searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue and I came across this question with no answer. The comments above helped me to find the solution to my problem, so I decided to post it here. May simply be a difference between `data.table` versions (I am using version 1.11.8), since this is relatively old question.

The solution uses a `()` instead of a `.()` or a `list()` to declare the column names to be replaced:

```
colunas <- c("b","c")
x.dt[is.na(b), (colunas) := x.dt.replace]
```

Hope this is useful